# How I can draw n-fold torus?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How I can draw a torus, double torus and triple torus with the same style of the picture? 
I use tikz.
[image]

Comment: Maybe start [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348/how-to-draw-a-torus) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255318/tikz-once-punctured-torus).

Comment: There is no MWE, but for me the question is clear : provide an uniform way to draw a n-torus (for n=1,2,...).

Comment: It is not really too broad. `n`-torus are quite concrete objects in mathematics and are often discussed together. It would not make sense if one grab an `1`-torus from here and grab a `2`-torus with different style there.