# How to draw a CW complex diagram for a torus

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the following picture with tikz. [image]

I found this [Tikz: Once punctured torus?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255318/tikz-once-punctured-torus) post which is extremely close to what I want, but I am not good enough at tikz to modify this. Any help would be appreaciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. In the future, when you post a question, you should always provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: I will do that next time I make a post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a trick using doubled lines and adjusting the `xscale` to give the appearance of a torus.

[image]

The first two `draw` commands produce the top and bottom halves of the torus. The `thick,white` lines cover the overlap.

The next four `draw` commands produce the meridional circle (half dashed), followed by the longitudinal circle (half dashed). You can adjust the `looseness` and `line width` however you like.

Finally, the `intersections` library is used to find the vertex and a filled circle is drawn. (Since the `xscale` is 2, an ellipse is needed.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=2]
    \draw[double distance=15mm] (0:1) arc (0:180:1);
    \draw[double distance=15mm] (180:1) arc (180:360:1);
    \draw[thick,white] (.6,0)--(1.37,0); \draw[thick,white] (-.6,0)--(-1.37,0);
    \draw[line width=.3, looseness=.3, name path=mer] (0,-1.75cm-.2pt) to[out=0,in=0] (0,-.25cm+.2pt);
    \draw[line width=.3, dashed, looseness=.3] (0,-1.75cm-.2pt) to[out=180,in=180] (0,-.25cm+.2pt);
    \draw[line width=.3, looseness=1.3, name path=lon] (1.375cm+.1pt,0) to[out=-90, in=-90] (-1.375cm-.1pt,0);
    \draw[line width=.3, dashed, looseness=1.3] (1.375cm+.1pt,0) to[out=90, in=90] (-1.375cm-.1pt,0);
    \fill[name intersections={of=mer and lon, by=v1}] (v1) ellipse (.2mm and .4mm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. It may seem strange, but we usually don't thank contributors in the comments. We show appreciation by upvoting (when you have sufficient reputation) and [accepting the most helpful answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).